# stratified sampling without k fold

Tags: python, machine-learning, sampling

Can I use stratified sampling with 80% train 20% test split 
the data in python ?

I have looked into this and it is for kfold stratified sampling.
I'm not sure if I just put 0 as the number of iteration would work, because it is implemented in the cross-validation package and they assumed at least 2 folds!

```
StratifiedShuffleSplit(labels=[0 0 1 1], n_iter=3, ...)
```

Comment: Did you mean to say "test **to** split the data"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what exactly your question is, so let's just review the details of [sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedShuffleSplit()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html).

> This cross-validation object is a merge of StratifiedKFold and ShuffleSplit.

This means that the function is going to return a randomized, stratified, fold. What determines the number of folds given back to you is the `n_iter` parameter. If you set this to 0, then you will not receive anything in the functions response.

It's also possible that not all folds will be unique.

---

To answer what I think is your question **Can I use stratified sampling with 80% train 20% test split the data in python?**

Yes, let's look at the example code. By setting the test_size paramter to 0.2 (20%), you'll force your folds to make 80% training, and 20% testing.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedShuffleSplit
X = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5,5], [6,6], [7,7], [8,8], [9,9], [10,10]])
y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(y, 1, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

for train_index, test_index in sss:
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

>>> TRAIN: [0 6 3 9 2 5 1 7] TEST: [4 8]
```

Please let me know if this is what you were looking for and let me know if you have any other questions.